# How to make generalize dateFragment class for multiple Date controls?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I want to make generalize/common class call for multiple controls such as a From & To date dialog boxes
should use same class while call

here i have two labels lblSrchFrmDate & lblSrchToDate want to show date dialog for both

**do i need to create DatePickerFragment for each call?**

here is my code 
**DatePickerFragment.java** class will have

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

String formattedDt = null;
public Dialog onCreateDialog(View v) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {              
    formattedDt = DateUtil.setSelectedDateInSDF(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);              
    //lblSrchFrmDate .setText(formattedDt);<--- want to set selected date on label 
}
```

}

Code for onClick

```
// On click Of Label
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {        
    case R.id.lblSrchFrmDate:
        showDatePickerDialog(v);
        break;
    case R.id.lblSrchToDate:            
        showDatePickerDialog(v);
        break;
    }
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

how to set date for respective dialogbox call control using View v?
v.getId() gives me numeric id which shows me value id/datePicker which is not label id